# Animating an image to make it rotate in a circle

Tags: html, css, transform

I am working on image transforms, rotates, and keyframes, but I am having a bit of an issue trying to get an image to spin in a circle. I have it set to rotate 360deg and two keyframes 0 and 100. I am wanting the image to spin from the center point of the image, so it looks as if the loading circle is loading something.

Right now it seems the image spins from the top-left corner.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
#spinning-circle {
  animation-name: spinning-circle;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinning-circle">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbNlQ.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
#spinning-circle img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

to your styles

It's spinning on an offset because the image is bigger than the container. If you wish to move the origin of transformations, use the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property

Comment: Do you know how to make it not slow down at the end? So it's at constant speed?

Comment: @Sam You'll need to add the `animation-timing-function` property to `#spinning-circle` and provide it with `linear` instead of the default `ease`

Answer (score 4):

You need to give it a `transform-origin` property

```css
#spinning-circle {
  animation-name: spinning-circle;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 125% 125%;
    transform-origin: 125% 125%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 125% 125%;
    transform-origin: 125% 125%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinning-circle">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbNlQ.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Why do I need to give it the origin? It works without it. What is the purpose in this instance.

Comment: @Becky If you want to keep the natural height / width of your image, you have to have it